# what is the science on the process evaporative cooling?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that in evaporation process highly energetic molecule get latent heat and it changes the phase and rest of water is cooled,but I think water at high temperature is at up and low temperature at the bottom because of high density of water,but how is energy transfered from water at low temperature to high temperature to gain latent heat,how is it possible ?I am so confused?

Comment: No offence, but your question is very mixed up. If you read this link, then you can ask any specific questions on the parts you don't follow: http://www.evaptainers.com/updates/2014/8/6/the-sciance-of-evaporative-cooling

Comment: I did not get what i am seeking for. There is only the process given. but i am looking for the reason how is it possible to flow heat from colder water molecule to hotter molecule,at ordinary heat can flow from hotter body to colder.

Answer (score 1):

Molecules in a liquid are bound, and only break free when binding energy
is supplied (and absorbed in the evolution of a gas  molecule).  The rate of evaporation can be negative or positive, or zero when the liquid is
in thermal equilibrium with the vapor.

Thermodynamics requires that Gibbs free energy be minimized, that means that evaporation WILL take place, even below the boiling point of a liquid, as long as that binding energy is less than temperature times the evaporation entropy change.   Evaporation, melting, and dissolution all create entropy and are expected to
cause refrigeration for this reason.  The inverse causes heating (there are heat pads based
on crystallization activated by a small clicker).

It is appealing to think that the hot molecules escape the liquid and that causes the liquid to cool (and it's true), but that's not the whole story: the gas
evolved isn't higher temperature than the cooled liquid. In the absence of
heat sources or sinks, the phase change alone causes temperature rise or fall.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are 20 people at a family gathering and the average age is 50. If the 5 oldest people leave, the average age drops to say 30.

The same thing happens in evaporation. There are many molecules in a beaker, with a distribution of speeds, from low to high. The molecules are attracted to each other, so they tend to stick together. However, a few molecules with the highest speed have enough kinetic energy to escape from the others and leave the beaker. The average speed of the molecules remaining in the beaker falls.

What we measure as temperature is the average speed of molecules. So if the average speed falls, we see the temperature falling.